# pytest: how to skip the testcases and jump right up to cleanup if something goes wrong in setup?

Tags: python, pytest

I understand that in pytest, the preferred way for setup and cleanup is to utilize `yield`, like

```
class TestSomething():
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
    def setup_cleanup(self, request):
        ...
        yield
        ...

    def test_something(self):
        ...
```

Problem is, if there is a failure in the setup part, before `yield` happens, the cleanup code would not get a chance to run.

Is it possible that, when some critical failure occurs in setup, all testcases are skipped, and the control is taken over by the cleanup (after `yield` in the method `setup_cleanup`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setup_cleanup` triggers the test function, but it is still a function. An exception raised in any step will prevent the rest of it to be excited.

A work around will be to use `try finally`. It will allow the test and teardown to run without swallowing the exception

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def setup_cleanup(self, request):
    try:
        print('Setup')
        raise Exception("Setup Exception")
        yield
    finally:
        print('Teardown')

def test_example_test(self):
    print('Test')
```

With the exception

```
Setup
Teardown

test setup failed
self = <ExampleTest.TestSomething object at 0x045E6230>
request = <SubRequest 'setup_cleanup' for <Function test_something>>

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
    def setup_cleanup(self, request):
        print()
        try:
            print('Setup')
>           raise Exception("Setup Exception")
E           Exception: Setup Exception
```

And without

```
Setup
.Test
Teardown
```